# Datagridview cell style update

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, datagridview

I'm facing a strange problem with a datagridview.
I need to change the style of a selected cell (A) in response to the value of another cell (B) = x.
(A) is a textbox while (B) is a combobox.
I catch the event CellEndEdit and everything works fine when the user changes the value of (B): the style of (A) changes immediately.

Now, when I try to update the datagridview progammatically, this does not work.
The strange thing is that both ways share the same method, UpdateTimeChannelCell.
If I call this method programmatically, the datagridview does not update the style of its cells. I tried by updating, refreshing, invalidating the datagridview with no luck

```
        private void UpdateTimeChannelCell(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 3 || e.ColumnIndex == 5 || e.ColumnIndex == 7 || e.ColumnIndex == 9 || e.ColumnIndex == 11 || e.ColumnIndex == 13)
        {
            if ((int)this.dataGridView_TidKanaler.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == 0)
            {
                this.dataGridView_TidKanaler.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Value = new Time();
                this.dataGridView_TidKanaler.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Style = disableStyle;
            }
            else
            {
                this.dataGridView_TidKanaler.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex - 1].Style = enableStyle;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the disableStyle and enableStyle codes

Comment: this.enableStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { ForeColor = Color.Black, SelectionBackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue };
            this.disableStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { ForeColor = Color.White, SelectionBackColor = Color.White };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know all Styling for DataGridViews needs to occur within the DataGridView.CellFormatting event.

This event is your opportunity to change the default style/coloring of cells.

Comment: could you make an example on how the event could be used to catch the change of a value in a cell?

Comment: with the cell formatting event, you are not catching any one change, it fires on every cell every time the DataGridView changes, so you inspect the cell change the style based on the current state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Gent this statement "Styling for DataGridViews needs to occur within the DataGridView.CellFormatting " is not correct in one of my forms I update the cells values and set the style at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force refresh my grid to get the styles to update.
eg. this.dataGridView_TidKanaler.Refresh()

Comment: NO. This method does something completely different.